# Which transaction comes first in a block?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, web3.py

I'm calculating a wallet balance and just want to confirm transaction ordering.

Is transactionIndex a reliable indication of which transaction came first? Is transactionIndex = 1 executed before transactionIndex = 2? Or otherway around?

Or does EVM even operate in a conventional atomic way (I would assume that this is needed)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is transactionIndex a reliable indication of which transaction came first? Is transactionIndex = 1 executed before transactionIndex = 2? Or otherway around?

Yes. Miners decides which transactions goes to the block they mined and the order.

> Or does EVM even operate in a conventional atomic way (I would assume that this is needed)?

Yes. Everything is serialised.

Whay you need to understand that blocks themselves are not stable, but probabilistic. A fresh block you saw might not actually end up in the longest chain. Thus, the real-time balance might fluctuate and some transactions might be executed differently, or even undoed in the case of a swap trade.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think they are executed one after another, they are pretty much in a same block, so a block is like a "tick" for the network.
Most smart contract implement a feature that forbid people to have multiple transaction from the same address in the same block to avoid exploit.

Comment: I guess in case of tokens, there should be a transaction ordering or some kind mechanism to prevent those exploits...